# properly access key and value to handle multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following

```
@bucketitems = Bucketitem.group(:p_id).having('count("p_id") > 1').count(:p_id)
```

generates a hash of cases

```
{"00000450155"=>3, "00002860120"=>2, "00002870129"=>2, [...]}
```

If  `@bucketitems.first` called, an array is given `["00000450155", 3]`

How can each case now be invoked

```
@bucketitems.each do |key, value|
  @items = Bucketitem.where('p_id = ?', "00000450155").to_a
```

so that the resulting array can be processed (complete missing data, delete duplicate records...)?

```
@items = Bucketitem.where('p_id = ?', key).to_a
```

is returning nil...

Comment: it is doubtful that this code returns `nil`. maybe an empty collection at least?

Comment: that is what I thought, yet `irb(main):150:0> @items
=> nil` and that hash does state that three items respect the condition.

Comment: Can you confirm what Bucketitem model represents real world ? You seem to gather all all records with p_id present more than once. Is it to delete the duplicates from Bucketitem ?

Comment: @Maxence Your assumption is correct.  However I later found out the hang-up for the condition with `key` ...  somehow the double quoting is leading to a misinterpretation of the string; but I cannot explain this misinterpretation.  I did resolve the matter differently, but remain with this question mark...